# Ubuntu Problems with Pam Google Auth

Tags: 18.04, openvpn, authentication, pam, two-factor-authentication

I had a working OpenVPN server that used Google Authenticator for TFA. It was working perfectly fine for well over a year. Just last night/today it stopped working. I managed to track down the auth.log file and the following error:

```
openvpn(pam_google_authenticator)[1366]: Failed to read “/home/administrator/.google_authenticator” for “administrator”
```

I tried to change the read permission for the `.google_authenticator` file but that did not work.

I changed the file owner and group to root and to administrator. Neither one worked.

I read online that it might be a time zone issue and I updated the time zone to my time zone and not UTC. That also did not work.

How do I make it so pam.d is able to read `.google_authenticator` again?

Answer (score 0):

So this did not get enable pam.d to read `.google_authenticator`, but I did get my OpenVPN working again.

I had to create a new service user and a new folder that they owned. Then I had to move all of my `.google_authenticator` files into that folder. I renamed all of the files after their respective users name. Then I had to add the line

```
auth required /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_google_authenticator.so secret=/etc/openvpn/ga/${USER} user=goog forward_pass
```

to my openvpn pam file.

`/etc/openvpn/ga` is the folder that my google auth user (`goog`) owns. `${USER}` is a `pam_google_authenticator.so` variable that is the username of the user trying to login. There is another `pam_google_authenticator` variable for the user's home directory (`${HOME}` or `~`), but it cannot be used with the `user` option for `pam_google_authenticator`.

[This](https://egonbraun.medium.com/using-google-authenticator-mfa-with-openvpn-on-ubuntu-16-04-774e4acc2852) article was very helpful. It explained a lot of the steps. It says to create the new user and group, create the directory for the Google Authenticator files, and give them appropriate permissions. Then it gave the specific line of how to run pam under a different user.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to AskUbuntu :) Could you please [edit your answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1417222/edit) with a bit more information from the related article? Answers like these are very helpful short-term, but if that site ever goes down, or changes directories, any additional required information may be lost. Glad you were able to solve your issue!

Comment: I know I hate it when people do exactly what I just did. I just wanted to get the basics of what I had done out before I forgot. Thank you for making sure I help provide a higher quality answer :)